# Python3 unable to find a package module

Tags: python, module, package

I have a file called dns_poison.py that needs to call a package called netscanner.  When i try and load the icmpscan module from dns_poison.py I get this message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'icmpscan'
```

I've done a sys.path and can confirm that the correct path is in place. The files are located at D:\PythonProjects\Networking\tools and D:\PythonProjects appears when I do a sys.path.

Here is my directory structure:

```
dns_poison.py
netscanner/
    __init__.py
    icmpscan.py
```

Code snippets for the files are as follows:

**dns_poison.py**

```py
import netscanner
```

**netscanner\__init__.py**

```py
from icmpscan import ICMPScan
```

**netscanner\icmpscan.py**

```py
class ICMPScan:
    def __init__(self, target, count=2, timeout=1):
        self.target = target
        self.count = count
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.active_hosts = []
       # further code below here....
```

I don't understand why it cannot find the module, as I've used this exact same method on other python projects without any problems. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `python dns_poison.py`, the importer checks the module path then the local directory and eventually finds your `netscanner` package that has the following available:

```
netscanner
netscanner.icmpscan
netscanner.icmpscan.ICMPScan
```

Now I ask you, where is just `icmpscan`? The importer cannot find because well, it doesnt exist. The `PYTHONPATH` exists at wherever `dns_poison.py` resides, and doesn't append itself to include the absolute path of any imported modules because that simply not how it works. So `netscanner` can be found because its at the same level as `dns_poison.py`, but the importer has no clue where `icmpscan.py` exists because you havent told it. So you have two options to alter your `__init__.py`:

1. `from .icmpscan import ICMPScan` which works with Python 3.x
2. `from netscanner.icmpscan import ICMPScan` which works with both Python 2.x/3.x

Couple of references for you:

- [Python Import System](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)
- [Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) recommend you ref section 6.4.2 Intra-package References

Comment: Thank you, updated my init file to match your first option and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to think about this is imports should be handled relative to the program entry-point file. Personally I find this the most simple and fool-proof way of handling import paths.

In your example, I would have:

```
from netscanner.icmpscan import ICMPScan
```

In the main file, rather than add it to **init**.py.

Comment: Entirely depends on if `netscanner` will be made as a package for other uses